# Combine two BDIC files from Chrome (hunspell) into one

Tags: google-chrome, dictionary, hunspell

I have two BDIC (binary dictionary?) files from Google Chrome spell checker (based on hunspell). I want to combine this two files into one single BDIC for all words.

Here is a [reader/writer](http://www.google.com/codesearch#wZuuyuB8jKQ/chromium/src/third_party/hunspell/google/bdict_reader.h&q=file%3a%28/%7C%5E%29third_party/hunspell/google/bdict_reader%5C.h%24&exact_package=chromiumos&type=cs&l=1) (chromium/src/third_party/hunspell/google/bdict_reader.h) of this format from Chrome sources (LGPL/C++)

How can I combine two files with C++ or command-line utility?

Comment: Recent Chrome/Chromium versions (47+) will use several languages for spell checking at same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Merging two hunspell dictionaries is easy, there are tools like https://github.com/arty-name/hunspell-merge that can help you merge any number of source dictionaries together.

Creating `bdict` file that Chrome understands is trickier. Chrome uses this format for optimizations and uses `convert_dict` tool internally to convert `aff` and `dic` files to `bdict`. I couldn't find this tool online so it left only one option, building it from Chromium sources. Google has a pretty straight forward setup that if executed carefully will let you build this tool. First you have to follow http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code to obtain the code and setup your environment base on your platform. After that execute `ninja -C out\Debug convert_dict` and if completed without errors, find your `convert_dict` executable under `out/Debug` folder.

You cannot add custom language to Chrome (as far as I know) so you have to replace one of the predefined ones. I suggest installing one of the languages you don't understand and use it for your merged one. The `bdict` files can be found in Chrome user profile folder.

Comment: Custom languages are not required, but Vivaldi browser added several additional languages to Blink engine. I just want to merge two languages I use (write) every day. Does chromium code include aff and dic files to generate dictionaries?

Comment: Yes it includes them as a dependency to third party modules.